# Openpyxl - How can I iterate through a column to copy values and sort based on condition

Tags: python, excel, copy, openpyxl, paste

I am new to Python. I am trying to write a script which will copy values from one excel file to another and sort them based on the value in column A. My code is only copying the final value that meets the condition, not all values. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']

mr = ws.max_row
mc = ws.max_column

mr2 = ws2.max_row
mc2 = ws2.max_column

for i in range(2, mr + 2):
    for j in range(1, mc + 1):
        if ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "A":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
        elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "B":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
        elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "C":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

increase mr2 by 1 when value == "C"

```
for j in range(1, mc + 1):
    if ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "A":
        ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
    elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "B":
        ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
    elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "C":
        ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
        mr2 += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but it put an empty cell between "Orange" and "Lemon" in Column B. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

increase mr2 by 1 when corresponds values are None/Blank

```
for i in range(2, mr + 2):
    for j in range(1, mc + 1):
        if ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "A":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
            # check wheater B or C column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
            if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value !=None:
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value!=None:
                    mr2 += 1
        elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "B":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
            # check wheater A or C column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
            if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value !=None:
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value!=None:
                    mr2 += 1
        elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "C":
            ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
            # check wheater A or B column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
            if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value !=None:
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value!=None:
                    mr2 += 1
```